# How to graph an equation in the form z=x*y (programme needed)

Tags: math, graph, equation

i would like to graph this kind of equation, z=x*y. I would like to set intervals like -n< x <-n and so on, to see how z varies in function of x and y at the same time. I also need to check the value of z at given x and y and see where z is at its maximum, for example. Thanks and have all a nice day!
Edit: the equation i am trying to study is z=x * (164+0.25y)
where 0 < x < 2.5 and 0 < x < 700.
P.S. I don't understand the downvotes, I kindly asked for a question in a polite way, providing as many details as I could.

Comment: Can you narrow down to some things you've tried and are also thinking of trying? Maybe which programming language you're using, etc?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I am not using a programming language nor do I need a custom programme to do this. I need a math/graph programme to do the things listed above.

Answer (score 2):

This question may be a little outside of the scope of this site, but in regards to a graphing program:

One of the easiest ways to determine things about graphs is to use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) a computational knowledge engine. A quick tour on the site and just trying a few things out should get you to where you want to go pretty quickly.

Since you appear new to this site, check out some of the [Stack Overflow Basics](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and be sure to up-vote any help you get or questions you may find helpful.

Comment: So this plot on wolframAlpha would be [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x+*+%28164%2B0.25y%29+%2C+0+%3C+x+%3C+2.5%2C+0+%3C+y+%3C+700](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x+*+%28164%2B0.25y%29+%2C+0+%3C+x+%3C+2.5%2C+0+%3C+y+%3C+700)